# Asp.net: how to add a using inside a script tag

Tags: asp.net

Let's say I am in source mode of a web page.

```
<script runat="server">
  //Code inside
</script>
```

How do I add **using** statements so I don't have to use the fully qualified names of classes.

Thanks for helping

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<%@ Import Namespace="MyNamespace" %>
```

Outside the script tag. Alternatively you can [add them in the web.config](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms164642.aspx).